# Interactive animation between container view controllers Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift

I am building an app which has a 'master view controller' one comparable to a navigation controller or TabBarController which houses a container view.

I switch between these child view controllers via UIButtons that are resident in the master view and appear above the container view to allow for navigation.

I have looked intensively and have understood that Apple do some magic to allow transitions interactively (with their custom containers) which isn't available in the public APIs.

Does anybody have a solution for interactively transitioning between child view controllers using the pan gesture right to left (and vice versa)?

Thanks!

Comment: have you looked into transitioning API? It should allow you to do what you need to do, if I understood you correctly. There is nice tutorial on raywenderlich.com: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

Comment: @Lope thank you for your reply. I have looked into the API and specifically tried to implement the solution in the post, however the child view controllers seem to work differently.

Comment: @JoshuaD it depends on the transitions you like to implement. You can treat views of child view controllers as regular subviews of 'master view controller'. Which means you can run the animation on the child view controllers' view.

Answer (score 0):

**Alternative Solution**

Solution found was to use a UIScrollView and enable both paging (for the bounce effect) and scrolling for a set direction. Useful example can be found here: https://github.com/jakespracher/Snapchat-Swipe-View

Comment: hey you got any success, other that the library you mentioned. Its not working in my case. ?